# How to check whether a function is already called in java?

Tags: java, android

I have called a method twice in my Android Java project but i want to invoke it only once. When I am calling the method for a second time, I want to check whether the method has already been invoked or not. Code is something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    //called with certain condition
    private void a(){
         c(); //first call
    }

    private void b() {
         c(); //second call,check here whether function is invoked already or not,if invoked not invoke here or vice-versa
    }

    //called with certain condition
    private void c() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Using the `function` keyword? Or is this meant to be pseudo-code?

Comment: Sorry, the terminology and pseudo-code is confusing wrt Java, imo.

Comment: Once per object of the class?

Comment: How many objects of this class wwill be created?

Comment: Please provide a better example with real names, we do not know what you are trying to achieve now. Multiple solutions are possible, which one you should use depends on what you are trying to do (WHY do you want to run only once but call 2 times)

Comment: I am extending a class in android programming

Comment: Unless you're teaching a freshman algorithms class, **use real code**. (Real, compilable-ish, and formatted.)

Comment: @Amrendra But this still doesn't explain **WHY** you want to run a method only once buy call it twice, you are giving us a XY problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: sry guys,this is a small concept of my project i can't explain all problem.thanx all for your response.I will try with these solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a boolean (or counter) to record whether the method has been called already.  But how you do it depends on *precisely* what you are trying to count / limit.

The following assumes that you use a counter:

- If you want to count all calls to the method in all contexts:

  ```
   private static int nos_calls;

   public void function c() {
       nos_calls += 1;
       // do the call
   }
  ```
- If you just want to count the calls of the method for a given object then:

  ```
   private int nos_calls;

   public void function c() {
       nos_calls += 1;
       // do the call
   }
  ```
- If you want to *prevent* the method from being called more than once:

  ```
   private int nos_calls;

   public void function c() {
       if (nos_calls++ == 0) {
           // do the call
       }
   }
  ```
- If the method could be called from different threads then you need to do the counting in a way that synchronizes properly; e.g.

  ```
   private AtomicInteger nos_calls = new AtomicInteger();

   public void function c() {
       if (nos_calls.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
           // do the call
       }
   }
  ```
- And so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run only once in the whole run-time of the program use a class static variable. If you want to run once per object add an object member variable

```
class RunOnce {
     private static boolean methodAHasRunOnce = false;
     private boolean methodBHasRun = false;

     public void methodA() {
         if(RunOnce.methodAHasRunOnce) { return; }
         System.out.println("Hello from methodA!");
         RunOnce.methodAHasRunOnce = true;
     }

     public void methodB() {
        if(this.methodBHasRun) { return; }
         System.out.println("Hello from methodB!");
         this.methodBHasRun = true;
     }
}
```

Now run:

```
RunOnce one = new RunOnce();
RunOnce two = new RunOnce();
one.methodA();  // Output: Hello from methodA!
one.methodB();  // Output: Hello from methodB!

one.methodA();  // No output
one.methodB();  // No output

two.methodA();  // No output
two.methodB();  // Output: Hello from methodB!

two.methodA();  // No output
two.methodB();  // No output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
class A{
    static boolean calledBefore = false;
    public void a(){
    ....
         c();
    }
    public void b(){
    ....
         c();
    }
    public void c(){

         if(!calledBefore){
             //This will be executed if c() is not called before
             //Do magic here

             calledBefore = true;
         }
    }
}
```

`calledBefore` should be non-static if you want to have multiple instances of class A and each instance is allowed to call `c()` once.

Answer (score 1):

I see here 2 solutions:

1. Do this by condition check

---

```
public Clazz {
    //private static boolean check = false; // if you want your method to be run once per class
    private boolean check = false; // if you want your method to be run once per class instance

    public void c() {
        if(check) {
            return;
        }
        check = true;
        ....
    }
```

---

1. Do this by intercepting method calls (e.g. Java dynamic proxies, javassist, asm, etc.) or using AOP

But you'll have to have an interface for this:

```
public class TestInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    //private static boolean check = false;
    private boolean check = false;

    private Object yourObject;

    public TestInvocationHandler(Object object) {
        yourObject = object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
        throws Throwable {
        if(check) {
            return null; // or whatever you need
        }
        check = true;
        return method.invoke(yourObject, args);
    }
}
```

and then you would create your objects like this:

```
ObjectInterface i = (ObjectInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(ObjectInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
                       new Class<?>[] {ObjectInterface .class},
                       new TestInvocationHandler(new MyImplementingClass()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a static field to the class that contains the function that is modified in the function (for example just incementing it) to keep track of the invokes.

Answer (score 0):

Aspects would be a general solution to this problem. I'm absolutely not an expert by any means (and this example has not been tested), but it would go something like:

```
@Aspect
public class CallOnlyOnceAspect {

  @Pointcut("call(* methodThatShouldBeInvokedOnlyOnce(..))")
  void methodThatShouldBeInvokedOnlyOnce() {}

  @Around("methodThatShouldBeInvokedOnlyOnce()")
  public Object preventMultipleCalls(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    // You need to implement this method for your particular methods/counters
    if (hasAlreadyExecuted(thisJoinPoint)) {
      return null;
      // or equivalent return value,
      // e.g. you may have cached the previous return value
    }
    Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    // Maybe cache result against thisJoinPoint
    return result;
  }

}
```

Much more detail can be found in these places:

- http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html
- http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-joinPoints.html